# How to know when the MPMoviePlayerController has been paused in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, notifications, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to add an overlay view for my video when the video is paused by the user. Is there any way to get the pause notification from MPMoviePlayerController?

According to [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW103), there should be ways to do this but I can't find which notification should I use for this purpose.

**Quote:**

> In addition to being notified when
>   playback finishes, interested clients
>   can be notified in the following
>   situations:
>
> -When the movie player begins playing, **is paused**, or begins seeking forward
>   ...
>   For more information, see the Notifications section in this reference.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I assume you know about delegates and protocols as a means of receiving callbacks?

There's another global mechanism called notifications too.

You can do this via

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(playbackStateChanged) 
    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Then, within playbackStateChanged, you can fetch the playbackState

```
 - (void) playbackStateChanged {

   _player.playbackState; // reading the playback

 }
```

The step of reading playbackstate directly from the player is specified in the docs

> To get the current playback state, get the value of the playbackState property of the movie player object.

Comment: i get a warning ```MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification was deprecated in iOS 9.0```